# How to open recently closed or hide form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, forward

I've researched thoroughly but still i cant find the best solution for this..
I have a 3 buttons, BACK - HOME - FORWARD ..

This is just like the buttons on the upper left of browser .. and im trying to do this on a form..

what i have is this ..

the back button code is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
}

// simply hiding the form .. so that the previous form will be shown..
```

the home button code is this..

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (Application.OpenForms[i].Name != "HomePage")
            Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
    }
} 

// this will show the HomePage form and close other forms whos name is not "HomePage"
```

the Problem is when i press the Back Button , im hiding it .. how can a button will re open a previously closed or hided form ?

I hope you can Help me! Thanks!

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ???????
}
```

Comment: You should consider naming your buttons with a meaningful name ;)

Comment: im sorry.. ill do it next time i post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to store a reference to the form that you wish to open again.

There are a couple of options to do this, but if you simply wanted to allow the user to go "Forward" once, you could just store a reference to the form like so:

```
internal class MyHistory {
    internal static Form LastForm;
}

// ........

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyHistory.LastForm = this;
    this.Hide();
}

// ........

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyHistory.LastForm.Show();
}
```

Of course, you could maintain a full stack of history items and traverse back/forwards through them if you wanted to be more comprehensive than this.

Note that, if you `.Close()` your form, you won't be able to reopen it as the reference will be disposed of once it is closed. This method would only work if you were to `.Hide()` it, which keeps the form instance valid, just hides the form from the user's view.

Comment: ok, this what happens to the code

i open form2 from form1, i open form3 from form2

i press the back button, form3 hide..

but when i press forward "null reference exception was unhandled" error ..

but if i open form3 again from form2 then press the forward.. it opens form3 again ..

i think what happens is when i press the back button, the next press is the one who got record on myhistory..

Comment: @JurelJacinto Did you update your 'Back' button code to store the reference to the form? It won't be null if you have set it. Also make sure you're using `Hide` not `Close`...

Comment: yes i did .. this is my code in 'back' button .. 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyHistory.LastForm = this;
            this.Hide();
        }

but its just what ive said that is happening ..

Comment: Sir Rudi , any idea why is it happening ?

Comment: @JurelJacinto The only thing that I can think of is that you're `Close`ing the form at some other point, or you haven't changed the button on every form that you're `Hide`ing.

Comment: i did everything you said.. i think the value of MyHistory.LastForm of form3 cant pass to the form2.. so when i open the form3 again .. and click the forward button.. another form3 is being shown. thanks anyway.. cant seem to finish this project.. thanks a lot.. godbless :)

Comment: @JurelJacinto Don't think like that of course you can finish it ;) Did you put the class in a separate file? (I mean, it shouldn't be a subclass of your form, because that definitely will be `null`)

Comment: i actually put the internal class MyHistory inside public partial class Form3 : Form {} .. is it fine ? i dont get it when you said another file ..

Comment: @JurelJacinto Well then yes, that is your problem, simply move it into another class file (or just outside of your `partial class`). At the moment, it's only accessible for that 1 `Form`.

Comment: thats it! i made a mistake .. im very sorry for troubling you! and thanks a lot! :) godbless sir Rudi! :)

Comment: @JurelJacinto Not a problem, glad you've got it fixed! :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use a form list which holds all initialized forms. that way you can hide, show, add and remove forms dynamically.

```
List<Form> lstForms = new List<Form>();
```

then when you add a form:

```
Form newForm = new Form();

lstForms.Add(newForm);
```

Hiding a Form:

```
lstForms(x).Hide(); //x = index of Form you want to hide
```

Showing a Form

```
lstForms(x).Show(); //x = index of Form you want to hide
```

Removing a Form (when closing it for example)

```
lstForms.RemoveAt(x);
```

that way you can dynamically work with forms and it is much easier to keep an overview if you have many forms...